# Flutter text in rotated box not staying centered

Tags: flutter, dart

This one is not easy to explain so I think an image is best:

[image]

I have this text "PACKED" appear after you swipe a card to the right with your finger, to mark it as packed.

I am struggling with having the rotated text centered horizontally. If I make my window size bigger its perfectly centered like this:

[image]

But As the window size gets smaller it doesn't stay centered even when there is enough room for the text.

Code snip-it:

```
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 1,
          child: Visibility(
            visible: gearItems[index].isPacked,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              child: Container(
                color: const Color(0xFF2b8293),
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 1, 4, 1),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      'PACKED',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 9,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          letterSpacing: 2,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(
                              255, 255, 255, 255)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 1,
          child: Visibility(
            visible: true,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 20,
                width: 100,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: const Color(0xFF2b8293),
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 1, 4, 1),
                  child: Text(
                    'PACKED',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 9,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        letterSpacing: 2,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).